# How to create ddl file with spring data and java based configuration?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have my spring data JPA configuration up and running. I'd like to get a **ddl sql file** from my annotated entities.

I know this has been asked many times. But I could not find something usefull explaing how to do this with java based spring configuration.

This is my JPA set-up:

```
@Bean(name = BEAN_ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY)
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = createLocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource());
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
    em.setPersistenceUnitName(getPersistenceUnitName());
    em.setPackagesToScan(getPackagesToScan());
    processOptionalProperty(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, em);
    processOptionalProperty(HIBERNATE_JDBC_BATCH_SIZE, em);
    processOptionalProperty(EHCACHE_CONFIGURATIONRESOURCENAME_PROPERTY, em);
    em.afterPropertiesSet();
    return em.getObject();
}

@Bean(name = BEAN_HIBERNATE_JPA_VENDOR_ADAPTER)
public HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    adapter.setShowSql(Boolean.parseBoolean(getPropertyValue(HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL_PROPERTY)));
    adapter.setDatabasePlatform(getPropertyValue(HIBERNATE_DATABASE_PLATFORM_PROPERTY));
    adapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
    return adapter;
}
```

The hbm2ddl is set like this:

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

This configuration creates the necessary database tables at application start-up. How can I get an sql script containing all the ddl commands to set-up the DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of googling and try and error this is the solution I found.

To generate a ddl script you need the [maven hibernate3:hbm2ddl plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/hibernate3-maven-plugin/hbm2ddl-mojo.html). To get the plugin I added this to my `pom.xml`:

```
        <plugin>
            <!-- run "mvn hibernate3:hbm2ddl" to generate a schema -->
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <components>
                    <component>
                        <name>hbm2ddl</name>
                        <implementation>jpaconfiguration</implementation>
                    </component>
                </components>
                <componentProperties>
                    <persistenceunit>eai</persistenceunit>
                    <outputfilename>ddl-file.sql</outputfilename>
                    <drop>false</drop>
                    <create>true</create>
                    <export>false</export>
                    <format>true</format>
                </componentProperties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

The nasty bit to find was the the dependency section. Thanks [to this blog post](http://frightanic.com/software-development/maven-hbm2ddl-fixing-java-lang-arraystoreexception-sun-reflect-annotation-enumconstantnotpresentexceptionproxy/) to point this out.

The second thing I got stuck was the persistence unit name. This is configured by placing a file called `persistence.xml` into your `META-INF` directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="eai">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect" />
            <!-- other properties ... -->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This file also contains the hibernate dialect. This is important to get the sql that makes your db happy.

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you for sharing your final solution! Just had to change the dialect to use Oracle in our case. Also, as the author stated, remember to run "mvn hibernate3:hbm2ddl" to generate a schema. Just doing Maven Install from Eclipse won't do it.

Comment: Thank you for your effort and for sharing this great solution. Worked as expected with Hibernate 4.